# print JSP table using JSTL tags

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to print a table with 2 columns and 5 rows (*10 items at a time in table*) displaying icons and text in each cell. However I have my Controller that returns a list of 14 item values.

I am able to get the values to the JSP read and iterate and paint the table using JSTL     `<c:forEach>` tag.

```
<c:forEach var="appcode" items="${result.appCodeList}" varStatus="rowCounter">
    <li id="listappcode" class="leftside">
    ${appcode}
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

The challenge for me here is on click of the "NEXT" button, my table should refresh and display the rest of the items on the page *excluding the 10 items*.

So to put in much simple statement first time the table will display 10 items and on click of NEXT it will display only 4 items (it is like flipping a page). How can I achieve this with JSTL tags where I break (I know break/continue is not available in JSTL) the loop and continue display the next items on click of button where I left last?

Comment: This isn't responsibility of JSTL. This is the responsibility of the controller / business logic. In your specific case, the `appCodeList` should hold **exactly** those items you need to display. With the next/previous buttons, just pass a request parameter "firstrow" along so that the controller / business logic knows which items to put in `appCodeList`. Look at Google, it isn't loading/copying those zillion of records from DB into Java memory and then displaying only 10 of them. No, it just loads exactly those 10 records which the enduser requested, which is much much faster.

Comment: This is the JSP we are trying to write on Scanner (like the one that is used in stores to scan cartons/items). Also one of the reason I am looking to get all the values to the UI is to avoid to go back to the Controller because I am sure the list of items would not more than 25 at any point of time. Also as you would know for a scanner the trip to the controller would be bit slow. Hence I am trying to get the whole list and do the refresh on client side.

Comment: Cache the results in the session then? This way you can keep your requests nicely idempotent (bookmarkable).